# How to add AddDbContext in Class Library (No Startup.cs file)?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

We are setting up a Monitor Service(`Worker Service` + Class libraries A,B,C) as a Worker Service Application, and  Plugin(DatasourceMonitor.OrderImport) which is a `Class Library .NetCore Framework` have classes X,Y,Z (which are derived from class A,B,C).

These independent `Class Libraries` have access to a `DbContext` (here KPDbContext) which have separate connection(MicroArchitecture).
The Plugins-> X.dll is added to Worker Service.

The Folder Structure is provided below:

[image]

In earlier version we added DBContext inside the Program.cs of Worker Service as

```
services.AddDbContext<KPDbContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:ServerAddress").ToString()));
```

But now KPDbContext is present in another project, We need to access separately as per classes X,Y,Z.

**DEMOCODE(ISSUE IS HERE)**

```
 public class X : A
    {
        
        public void Run(ServiceSettings settings, DataSource dataSource, string path)
        {
            // How to activate this KPDbContext ??????
            using (var entities = new KPDbContext ())
            {
                entities.Interfaces.Add(new Interface()
                    {
                        CreatedDateTime = now,
                        TableId = 0,
                        TableName = "Order"                        
                    });
                    entities.SaveChanges();
              }
```

I created a connection string on this as appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "data source=auto123.com;initial catalog=KAPPDBS;user id=sa;password=sa123!;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
}
```

Kindly advice us, pretty stuck into this. If any documentation kindly send link too.

Comment: It's really unclear what your scenario is. What does _"We need to access separately as per plugins"_ mean? A DLL doesn't run, it's loaded by an application. Where is your application?

Comment: @CodeCaster  Edited.

Comment: Still not clear. Where is the application that calls this code, and why can't it pass a DbContext?

Comment: Setting up the DI Container is done solely in the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), which is part in the startup project of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class library have't `setup.cs` but can you fixed this iusse by simple and easy way.

**First**: Create a class ex `ModelsSetting.cs` in **class library project**

**Second**: create a function for return `connectionString`

**Code**

```
    public static class ModelsSetting
    {
         public static string ConnectionString
         {
                get => "yourConnectionString"; // you can get form App.config fie
         }
         public static void Configure(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
    }
```

**Third**: change `YourContext`

```
if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
          optionsBuilder.Configure();
```